# Creating a new ticket in Request Tracker using javascript fetch / REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rt

I am trying to connect the contact form on our react website to a queue in Request Tracker. We need to create a new ticket in a specific queue when someone submits the form. I have been all over the docs, the wiki, and the forum, and I am struggling to find examples of how to do this. Answers regarding Python, PHP and C# seem to suggest it should be possible with a simple fetch/POST request...! If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.